# Как установить пакет?

Tags: freebsd

Есть FreeBSD 8. Хочу установить `open-vm-tools`. Основная проблема в том, что нет доступа в интернет.

```
cd /usr/ports/emulators/open-vm-tools
make install
```

При запуске данного когда shell пытается залезть на сайт

```
Attempting to fetch from http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/open-vm-tools/open-vm-tools/2009.05.22/.
```

Скачал непосредственно сам архив, однако попытка установить не увенчалась успехом.

```
make install
make: don't know how to make install. Stop
```

Вырисовывается 2 метода установки пакета 
1) Как то поменять путь с sourceforge на свой?
2) Как установить сам пакет?

Comment: Подредактируйте hosts, как вариант, что бы вместо sourceforge он обращался на локалку.

Comment: Либо поправьте пути в самом установщике.